# Scrapy settings work using custom_settings but don't work in settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy, settings

I have been trying to edit some settings in my Spider but they only seem to work when I override the custom_settings dictionary in my custom Spider.

```
custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
    'FEED_URI': 'generalspider.json',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

When I put them in settings.py they don't seem to work. settings.py was supposed to work for all spiders. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`custom_settings` has priority over `settings.py`. So you'll have to remove the variables in `custom_settings` for the variables in `settings.py` to work.

Also please check if the class of your spider is derived from other classes (maybe spiders) and those base classes have their own `custom_settings`.

Comment: Yes right, my spider is derived from scrapy.Spider and there is custom_settings set to None, so you have to override that in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell scrapy where your setting is by set `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your `.env` file

like this

```
SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.py # path to your settings.py
```

**OR**  in your main spider

```
os.environ["SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "The path to my settings.py file"
```